# jQuery nesting DOM nodes > 3 levels deep

Tags: jquery, dom

Trying to nest newly created DOM nodes 3 levels deep. I'm using the following code:

```
var dom = $('<div>').append('<a>').append('<span>');
```

result of code above:

```
<div>
     <a></a>
     <span></span> 
</div>
```

desired output:

```
<div>
     <a>
          <span></span>
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dom = $('<div>').append('<a><span>')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dom = $('<div />')
              .append(
                  $('<a />')
                      .append(
                          $('<span />')));
```